# How to add a data disk to a vm in resource manager using the resource group template file?

Tags: powershell, azure

I would like to provision a server with azure resource manager that has a data drive.  What json do I add to my azure resource group template file in order to provision the server with a persistent data disk?

To be clear, I do not want to do this through the management portal after the server is provisioned through the resource group template.

Comment: A Google Search for `provision a server with azure resource manager that has a data drive` yields http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-windows-attach-disk/ as the third search result.

Comment: Yes. I've corrected the question.  I'm trying to provision the disk as part of the resource group template and not through the manager.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this?

Comment: I want to write me resource group template file to automatically provision the server with an extra drive when I Add-AzureResourceGroup in powershell.

Comment: I would note that the documentation is especially poor for this particular feature.

Comment: Eventually I was able to figure out that you can learn what resource types are available by running [`Get-AzureLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654582.aspx). This really isn't well documented. I don't have a Windows box handy, though...

Answer (score 0):

Yes..You can create an ARM template to provision disk or any other resources automatically..
You will have to make a few minor changes in ARM template code in a JSON,ruby,.NET or powershell file and redeploy it so that every time when you create a VM using the template a disk is provisioned automatically as you have specified in the template. [Lecture 23](https://www.udemy.com/fundamentals-of-azure-and-powershell/?couponCode=AZURE1943) of [fundamentals of azure and powershell](https://www.udemy.com/fundamentals-of-azure-and-powershell/?couponCode=AZURE1943) shows how to add a storage automatically by modifying JSON file..Using the same method you can automatically provision any resource through Azure ARM template

Comment: Your answer only gives some pointers for further research, but not a concrete solution to the problem. One option would be to leave it as a comment, as soon as your reputation allows.